# How to access a variable from a different class AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, levels

Ok so i want to access the player location from my spawner class but i am confronted with an error when i try to run it and i cannot for the life of me figure it out!

This is where i'm the values that i want are, in the "Player" class.

```
public function returnX():Number
{
  return this.x;                    
}

public function returnY():Number
{
  return this.y;            
}
```

Here is how i'm trying to access them, within the "Spawner" class

```
private function spawnEnemy(xPos:int, yPos:int):void {

  var enemy:enemySquare;
  enemy = new enemySquare();
  enemy.x = xPos;
  enemy.y = yPos;
  addChild(enemy);
  enemy.chase(playerArrow.player.returnX(), playerArrow.player.returnY());
}
```

I basically wanted to spawn a new enemy and then once it had spawned it was then going to perform the chase function that i had made in the "EnemySquare" class

```
public function chase(xValue:Number, yValue:Number):void{

  //store current x and y in a point var
  var curPos:Point = new Point (x,y);

  //store the mouse x and y in a var
  var targetPos:Point = new Point(xValue, yValue);

  var nextPos:Point = easeTo(curPos, targetPos, 0.01);

  this.x = nextPos.x;
  this.y = nextPos.y;       
}
```

I have imported all the stuff i need (i think) and i also made the player object a public static variable. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: D:\Uni\Actionscript\Shapes\src\objects\spawner.as(69): col: 28 Error: Access of possibly undefined property player through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: Where does `playerArrow` come from?

Comment: playerArrow is the player class

Comment: It's still not really clear where playerArrow comes from? Is "enemy.chase(playerArrow.player.returnX(), playerArrow.player.returnY());" on line 69 of "spawner.as"? Is this the line that causes the error?

Comment: Please tell us where `playerArrow` is created and how. Also show how you have made a static. We need these in relation to the code you have already provided. Also, can you explain `playerArrow.player`  If `playerArrow` is the player object, then why is `player` in the chain?

Comment: Ok sorry i can see i explained poorly haha.

Comment: PlayerArrow is the class and player is the instance of the class that i want the X and Y values for to give to the spawner class

Comment: So the compiler tells you there's a problem with player but for some reasons you think that's a problem with returnX() ... Can't you see that you need to fix the player problem first?

Comment: Nevermind guys i got it all started!

Comment: @Volcano Steve Is `playerArrow` static? or is `player` static? Is `player` a property in `playerArrow` the class? or is it a property within the `Spawner` class?

Comment: There are a couple of errors in your question (i.e Player class), but your error is that the `playerArrow` class does not have a static `player` property. Although it is your error i'm guessing it is not your problem. You just need `player.returnX()` instead of `playerArrow.player.returnX()`